# Create Pool of logins that can be checked in and out by protractor parallel runs

Tags: protractor

I have a large suite of protractor tests that currently are setup to run with a unique login per spec. This allows us to run the specs in parallel of each other. But now we are looking to use protractors built in parallel runs, where it runs the tests within a spec in parallel. Problem is we need the tests to all login to their own unique login. Rather than creating a unique login for each and every test. What I am trying to do is create a pool of tests that the tests would check out when they start, and then check back in when finished. This way we could have something like 10 logins for a spec of 50 tests, and run 10 of the tests at the same time. Each one checking out one of the logins and then checking it in for the next test to use.

My original thought was to create a two dimensional array, with a list of logins and a boolean that says whether that login is in use or not. Then I figured the beforeEach function could log in to the next available account and mark that login as checked out. Then have the afterEach log out and check the account back in. But I am struggling to find any way for the AfterEach to be aware of the login that needs to be checked back in.

So I need some way for afterEach to know which login the test that just finished was using.

Is there a way to do this? Or is there a better way to manage a login pool?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

We've done something similar using a .temp directory and files. What you could do is before the tests run, generate a list of 10 users represented by 10 files that contain a json of the username and password, for example. When a test starts running it reserves a user by deleting the file so that no other test can use it. When the test is done running you have it write the file back to the temp directory so that another test can then "reserve" the user.